# Центрировать span в div (position relative)

Tags: html, css

Есть HTML:

```
<div class="heroblock">
    <img class="heroimg" src="https://cdn.cloudflare.steamstatic.com/apps/dota2/images/dota_react/heroes/abaddon.png?" width="128" height="72"/>
    <a class="herotitle"><span >Abaddon (Offlane)</span></a>
</div>
```

Есть CSS:

```
.heroblock {
            border: 1px solid white;
            position: relative;
        }
        .heroimg {
            vertical-align: middle;
            display: inline;
        }
        .herotitle {
            font-size: 16pt;
            height: 72px;
            line-height: 70px;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }
```

Задача: сделать текст в  по середине всего div. Не писать right: 50%. Заранее благодарен

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.heroblock {
            border: 1px solid white;
            position: relative;
            display:flex;
        }
```

Больше информации о флексах (https://tpverstak.ru/flex-cheatsheet/)